# SVG viewbox rendering its position differently in IE compared to chrome

Tags: html, css, svg

I am rendering out my SVG sprite externally but I am having issues with the viewbox.

```
<svg class="more-info__icon" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <use xlink:href="/_client/images/svgs.svg#next"></use>
</svg>
```

In Chrome this render out fine but in IE the position on the SVG isnt correct. Here is my SVG sprite.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><symbol id="next" viewBox="25 25 50 50"><g fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-miterlimit="10"><circle stroke-width="3" cx="49.4" cy="50" r="18.9"/><path stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M45.6 57.1l9.6-7.1-9.5-7.1"/></g></symbol></svg>
```

Comment: If you look to the ["Browser compatibility" table](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use#Browser_compatibility) of the [MDN's article on `<use>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use), you can see that the Load from external URI is not supported in IE.

Answer (score -1):

With the following code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="next" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
    <g fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-miterlimit="10">
      <circle stroke-width="3" cx="49.4" cy="50" r="18.9" />
      <path stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M45.6 57.1l9.6-7.1-9.5-7.1" />
    </g>
  </symbol>
  <use xlink:href="#next" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" />
</svg>
```

I could not recreate the issue: (it's inline so the rendering could be different)

[image]

Comment: how does it answer the question?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a community, we post questions here for others to find, so that if they have the same problem they (hopefully) find a good answer to a question. I posted this to show that i could not find any issue with rendering a symbol with a use element.

Comment: I do not know how i could render an external element in a stackoverflow answer. Does the answer deviate to far from what you are asking? Could you rephrase the question or maybe give more information?

Comment: I think that the problem is indeed that OP does load external URI in its `<use>` element, which is not supported in IE [according to mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use#Browser_compatibility). Your answer just says that there is no problem if he does something else, it doesn't even point to the actual problem, and there is no solution clearly stated in it. Ps: to create a test case, you can use http://plnkr.co

Comment: I'm just pointing out that i could not find any problem if its inline svg, there would be no issue with the viewBox in IE then. Does that not solve the question at all?